# Ink Stamp for Depositing Checks

Tags: united-states, banking, deposits

If I had a personal checking account that I made frequent small deposits into, would it be possible to use a custom stamp instead of a signature endorsement?

What information would need to be on the stamp?

What if the check was made out to my wife (or to both of us)--would she need her own stamp?

It seems like something that would be easy to google, but I am not coming up with any good info.  Thanks for any help.

Edit: to clarify, it would be a joint account.  My wife does not share my last name (not sure if that matters).

Answer (score 2):

I have a stamp I use to deposit checks to my company account. It has the company name, account number and the words "for deposit only". For my personal accounts I use a stamp that only has "for deposit only", and sign it. That has worked for a while with no problems at two major US banks (in fact the company stamp was a free gift for opening an account at one of them).

The endorser should be the person that the check is payable to, so I guess you'll have to have a stamp for you and another one for your wife (or not write the name on the stamp, just sign).